# That which is seen cannot be unseen

Tags: discussion, spoilers

So, we're getting a lot of questions with fluff added to avoid spoilers from being seen on the question page.

Should we add some verbiage somewhere stating that there's a 200 character pre-spoiler requirement (that shouldn't be filled with SPOILERS SPOILERS SPOILERS, etc) if they choose to have spoilers in their question?

I counted the characters needed to make adiquate fluff, and it was around 194, which turns out to be a little less than 2 lines of text on the questions page.

And I know that I've been guilty of this, but I'm trying to see if people have suggestions on how to remedy these situations.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/89552/155668

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no way to remedy it.  All of the feature requests to fix the bug where spoilers show on the `/questions` page were rejected by the admins, so we're stuck with this workaround.

Also, the previews of questions that are posted in chat have more characters than the `/questions` page - 295 characters.

Comment: I think the questions page is more prevelant than the chat. I think we should add something on the Ask a Question page saying that any spoilers should be after 200 characters if they want them to be affective.

Comment: @OghmaOsiris Then I'd recommend we also have a feature request for a character count, so people know when they've hit 200 characters.

Comment: I agree. we should have that anyway.